# Create CheckBox Checked event in DataTemplate contained in Resource Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a `ResourceDictionary` that contains a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplateCheckBox">
    <Border BorderBrush="#55000000" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" x:Name="borderCheckBox">
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkModeled" IsChecked="{Binding Path=modeled}" Margin="2" />
        </Grid>         
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

At runtime I load the `DataTemplate` so I can pass it to another assembly:

```
var res = (DataTemplate)FindResource("CellTemplateCheckBox");
otherAssembly.SetTemplate(res);
```

The question is this:
How do I programmatically attach a `Checked` event to the contained `Checkbox` in this `DataTemplate` that is contained in a `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: Check out using Microsoft Blend for this. It makes this kind of stuff incredibly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I programmatically attach a Checked event to the contained Checkbox

Why do that when the code binds to the `modeled` property?

Simply do the processing necessary from a call from the setter of `modeled`. If processed from there, it can identify the who it came from as well as the status of the check.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy it may not apply but one should have all options known. My other thought was to simply subscribe to the checked event in the template and make sure the consumer implements the named method.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying or creating a Template and adding elements and events is not indeed a simple task.

You can try and find some help from this article I wrote a couple of years ago that creates a TabItem with the close button and creates thus the Close event that can be managed by other controls or Windows using the template. It is a little bit more complex than your example, but You can concentrate on the part explaining the creation of the event. It needs not only XAML but also a class. I hope this can help you

[The Article on templating](http://blogs.dotnetwork.it/sabrina/en/blog/un-tabitem-chiudibile-modificare-un-template-wpf/)

Comment: Thank you for responding @Sabrina_cs

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer that is simple, at least.  In the object that contains the `Checkbox`, catch the bubbled up event:
`<Grid CheckBox.Checked="chkBox_Checked">`
In the `chkBox_Checked` handler, you can test for `e.OriginalSource.Name` (have to test if `e.OriginalSource` is a `FrameworkElement` though) in `RoutedEventArgs` to see if it matches `"chkModeled"`.  If so, you know the `Checked` event came from the `Checkbox` from the DataTemplate.